# gnupg installation on windows

Tags: windows, pear, gnupg, pecl

I successfully installed pear & pecl on my windows machine.
Now, i would like to install gnupg extension using pecl.

My need is to get the gnupg.so extension for php7 to upload it on a linux server on which I have no rights. The extension does not exist on this server, this is the reason why I need to get it to transfer it.

When I run `pecl install gnup`on my machine, I get the following result:

```
C:\WEB>pecl install gnupg-1.4.0.tgz
6 source files, building
ERROR: The DSP gnupg.dsp does not exist.
```

After some research, I found out that I migth need a .dll but there is no way to find anything about it.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: You might be able to cross-compile and _copy_ it to your Linux box -- but are you sure you will be able to make PHP actually _load_ it? Anyway, I'd simply fetch the binary from the Linux distribution's repository, no matter whether you can use the package manager to download and extract it or doing so manually.

Comment: I don't really understand. What do you mean by "fetch the binary from the linux destribution's repository"?

Comment: Well, you're not root and cannot _install_ the package containing the GnuPG module for PHP. But nothing prevents you from downloading it manually. For example, the Debian package would be [`php/gnupg`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php-gnupg), with Download links at the bottom of the page. Similar pages also exist for probably all other Linux distributions. I still don't think you will be able to load the module without administrative privileges, though.

Answer (score 1):

`pecl install` downloads the source code and compiles it for the system `pecl` runs on. It will not work on a different system, especially not on a Linux one when you are compiling it on windows.

You have three options that will work, in order of preference:

1. Install the distribution-provided pecl-gnupg package
2. Run the `pecl install` command on your server
3. Setup an *identical* machine as your live server, run `pecl install` on it and copy the generated `.so` file to your live server.